# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not UploadedFile/ Streamlit txt file uploader error

Tags: python, streamlit, txt

I am working on creating a web app on Streamlit that can read 2 input txt files uploaded by the user and then execute some data manipulation on it and output a dataframe out of that.

An example txt file is attached and my code looks like below.

However, I receive the error: **TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not UploadedFile**

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```
def read_txt_file(file_path, start_line):
    #with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    file_data = file_path.read()
    print(file_data)

    lines = [line.strip() for line in file_data][start_line:]

    data = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(('ECC Production', '-', ' ', 'Whithouse S', '----------','|Date')):
            continue

        row = {}
        row['Date'] = line[:11].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['Time'] = line[11:20].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['Supplier'] = line[20:31].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['Changed By'] = line[31:44].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['Field Name'] = line[44:75].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['CoCd'] = line[75:80].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['POrg'] = line[80:85].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['New Value'] = line[85:121].replace('|', '').strip()
        row['Old Value'] = line[121:156].replace('|', '').strip()

        data.append(row)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.loc[~df['Date'].isin(['----------'])]
    df = df.loc[~df['Date'].isnull()]

input_files = st.file_uploader("INPUT Extraction", type=["txt"])


input2_files = st.file_uploader("INPUT2 Extraction", type=["txt"])


if st.button("Run"):

    if input_files and input2_files:
        input_df = read_txt_file(input_files, start_line=5)

        input2_df = read_txt_file(input2_files, start_line=18)

        final_df = pd.concat([input_df, input2_df], ignore_index=True)

        st.dataframe(final_df)
```

I made some changes on the code using StringIO, however I keep on getting error on data types:

TypeError: 'UploadedFile' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: Hi Tanishq, line 3 and at the line of input_df. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code a little, and the following works.

The type of `file_path` is `streamlit.runtime.uploaded_file_manager.UploadedFile`, `file_bytes` is `bytes`, and `file_data` is `str`.

It also looks like you want to iterate over the lines of the text file, so after decoding the `bytes` into a `str`, we do `.split("\n")` to split by newline.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


def read_txt_file(file_path, start_line):
    file_bytes = file_path.read()
    file_data = file_bytes.decode("utf-8").split("\n")

    lines = [line.strip() for line in file_data][start_line:]

    # same logic as before
    # ...

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.loc[~df["Date"].isin(["----------"])]
    df = df.loc[~df["Date"].isnull()]

    return df


input_files = st.file_uploader("INPUT Extraction", type=["txt"])

if st.button("Run"):
    if input_files:
        input_df = read_txt_file(input_files, start_line=5)
        print(input_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `st.file_uploader()` returns an `UploadedFile` type, not `str`or `bytes`. To be able to use that in the rest of your code you need to convert it:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

input_files = st.file_uploader("INPUT Extraction", type=["txt"])
if input_files is not None:
    # To read file as bytes:
    bytes_data = input_files .getvalue()
    st.write(bytes_data)

    # To convert to a string based IO:
    stringio = StringIO(input_files .getvalue().decode("utf-8"))
    st.write(stringio)

    # To read file as string:
    string_data = stringio.read()
    st.write(string_data)

    # Can be used wherever a "file-like" object is accepted:
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(input_files )
    st.write(dataframe)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader) is pretty good!